# Oracle SELECT every distinct column over every another distinct column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEST 
(
    CODE NUMBER,
    DATE_COL NUMBER,
    VAL NUMBER
);
```

With values:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST (code, DATE_COL, val) 
VALUES (1, 20210101, 1);
INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST (code, DATE_COL, val) 
VALUES (1, 20210102, 1);
INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST (code, DATE_COL, val) 
VALUES (1, 20210103, 1);
INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST (code, DATE_COL, val) 
VALUES (2, 20210101, 1);
```

As a result, I would like to get every distinct `DATE_COL` row over every distinct `CODE` row:

```
CODE|DATE_COL|VAL|
----+--------+---+
   1|20210101|  1|
   1|20210102|  1|
   1|20210103|  1|
   2|20210101|  1|
   2|20210102|  1| (new line)
   2|20210103|  1| (new line)
```

This is the distinct of every dates:

```
SELECT DATE_COL 
FROM TEMP_TEST 
GROUP BY DATE_COL
```

This is the distinct of every codes:

```
SELECT code 
FROM TEMP_TEST 
GROUP BY CODE
```

How do I get every dates over every codes, so that the result set has the multiplied size of the two above distinct result sets?

Comment: Cross join two  your queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t.code,
       d.date_col,
       COALESCE(t.val, 1) AS val
FROM   (
         SELECT DISTINCT date_col FROM temp_test
       ) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_test t
       PARTITION BY (t.code)
       ON (t.date_col = d.date_col);
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | CODE | DATE_COL | VAL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 20210101 | 1 |
> | 1 | 20210102 | 1 |
> | 1 | 20210103 | 1 |
> | 2 | 20210101 | 1 |
> | 2 | 20210102 | 1 |
> | 2 | 20210103 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91a704d249a4741b2af4e2dda42a8a5c)*

---

*Note: this also works when the `VAL` values are not identical as the correlation is kept between `code`, `date_col` and `val`. If you naively use `CROSS JOIN` then the correlation is not maintained and extra rows are likely to be generated. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e2da5e1020290ee18f23d2853f499611)*

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to perform triple self cross join:

```
SQL> select distinct a.code, b.date_col, c.val
  2  from temp_test a cross join temp_test b cross join temp_test c
  3  order by 1, 2, 3;

      CODE   DATE_COL        VAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1   20210101          1
         1   20210102          1
         1   20210103          1
         2   20210101          1
         2   20210102          1
         2   20210103          1

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

How it'll behave with *huge* tables, that's another question. If they aren't that *huge*, I guess it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform cartesian join between the distinct values of DATE_COL and CODE.
It is unclear what do you want to show from the VAL column, so I do not display it

```
select date_col_data.DATE_COL, code_data.code
from
(SELECT distinct DATE_COL 
FROM TEMP_TEST ) date_col_data,
( SELECT distinct code 
FROM TEMP_TEST ) code_data
```

db fiddle here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9cf8afb7b5e1d652ddb5362066f0970